# Bypass async task after a period of time

Tags: android, android-asynctask

To explain what I am trying to do:

My application is connected to a bluetooth printer and prints some data.
This is done in an AsyncTask (lets call it asyncPrint) so that the user can normaly use application in the meantime.

The asyncPrint prepares data and feeds it to the printer. Now to prepare data  another asyncTask (lets call its asyncData) is called that connects to a web service to get some data. Because I need the data before I print, I call it like this:

```
String a = ws.get();
```

So that printing waits until asyncData is done.

But if the internet connection is slow this can take up to 30seconds so what I want to do is that if I wait for 5seconds asyncData should be bypassed not stop or cancled and the printing should go through without the data from internet.

asyncData should still finish since it also saves some data to the database after it finishes.

Any ideas how to make this possible?

Comment: You need both Services and AsyncTasks, not just AsyncTasks. IntentService does both, use that. While you're at it, use a SyncAdapter for synching your data.  Start writing some code and post it here if you get stuck somewhere. You have an idea of what to do already, the trick is to just start writing the code. Don't worry if it's not perfect initially.

Comment: What do you want to do? want to cancel the task if you cancel it, it will stop to execute.

Comment: @BhavdipPathar I dont want to cancel it, just wait 5 seconds for ws.get() if its not done in that time than go pass it without canceling it.

Comment: @StephanBranczyk I will check intentService but can you more specifically tell me how this should be implemented that I can wait for async to finish for a period of time and bypass it after if it's not finished?

Answer (score 1):

How about this: you start both tasks together, but the task for printing is delayed by 5 seconds. If any data arrived from the server, use it, otherwise, go ahead without.

In pseudocode that will look some thing like this:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity{

    String dataFromServer;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Start both tasks
        startGetDataFromServerTask();
        startPrinterTask();
    }

    private void startGetDataFromServerTask() {
        new GetDataFromServerTask(new OnTaskFinished() {
            public void onTaskFinished(String result) {
                dataFromServer = result;

                // additionally
                saveToDatabase(dataFromServer);
            }
        }).execute();

        // OnTaskFinished is in interface callback that you use to pass the result from the
        // asynctask to your calling activity.
    }

    private void startPrinterTask() {
        // Delay the task by 5 seconds.
        // If the data from server managed to arrive, good, the printer task will have it.
        // Otherwise, it won't (you'll have to check for null in the task)
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                new PrinterTask(dataFromServer).execute();
            }
        }, 5 * 1000);
    }
}
```

Comment: I was thinking about this way, but if the internet is good the data comes in a second than the client has to unneceserily wait for 4seconds. Any work around ideas? :D

Comment: It can't cancel itself, but you can cancel it by using `removeCallbacks(Runnable r)`: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#removeCallbacks%28java.lang.Runnable%29

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can use Handler with post delay of 5 * 1000 mills. start both task together and inside handle verify the data is available if available then print with data other wise skip it. the first async task will also save the data in your database thank you.

Comment: I was thinking about this way, but if the internet is good the data comes in a second than the client has to unneceserily wait for 4seconds. Any work around ideas? :D

Comment: You can remove the handler handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null); inside your asyncData onFinsh method of asyn task. this will remove your  5 second callback.

Comment: That sounds like it could work. I will try it out and accept your answer if it works :)